# Gallery with javascript! 3 galleries on 1 site

Tags: javascript, gallery

I use this code for 3 galleries on 1 site. every gallery has other images. The problem is the first gallery is working in a loop, but the second and the third gallery stopping after one loop.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function cycleImages(){
          var $active = $('#cycler .active');
          var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
          $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
          $active.fadeOut(1700,function(){//fade out the top image
              $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
              $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
          });
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 4s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
    })</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eEpwK/3/

Comment: If you put up a fiddle / codepen with code that demonstrates what you have people are more willing and able to help.

Comment: I hope this fiddle contains all code thats nessasary

Comment: question upvote for adding the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you are using the `id="cycler"` multiple times. You may already know that within a page each id must be unique. The first thing i did was to change your html-code to this:

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="cycler1" class="slides">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">
   <div id="cycler2" class="slides">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the ids for cycler are different now (cycler1, cycler2, cycler3) i changed the css to this:

```
.slides { position:relative; }
.slides img { position:absolute; z-index:1 }
.slides  img.active { z-index:3 }
```

And finally the javascript to wire it all up. This code is nearly the same as yours with a single difference. Instead of hardcoding the id-selector `#cylcer` into the function i pass the id-selector as the argument `sel`.

```
function cycleImages(sel){                                              
    var $active = $(sel + " .active");
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) 
                    ? $active.next() : $(sel + " img:first");
    //move the next image up the pile
    $next.css('z-index',2);
    //fade out the top image
    $active.fadeOut(1700,function(){
        //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
        //make the next image the top one       
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
    });
}
```

Now you just have to call the function for each id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 4s
   // cycleImages();
   setInterval(function(){
                cycleImages("#cycler1");
                cycleImages("#cycler2");
                cycleImages("#cycler3")
            }, 2000);
})
```